v-slot can only be used on components or <template> tags. Using <router-view> (plugin:vite:vue)
  <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
    <component
      :is="Component"
      class="container"
      ref="componentRef"
    />
  </router-view>

This is my code. It compiles perfectly fine with vue compiler.
But we are migrating to Vite. On running same with Vite, I get below error:
[plugin:vite:vue] v-slot can only be used on components or <template> tags.
Router view code is as per standards: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/router-view-slot
What is the workaround.

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . There are vite+vue setups in codesandbox and stackblitz. There's no such problem with vite in general. The error suggests that router-view is not a component, e.g. it could be not registered

Is there any way to tell vite that  is a component from '"vue-router": "^4.1.6",'

If you can render  without v-slot and it's rendered and doesn't stay  element in DOM, then it works

Have you tried something like this?
<router-view>
  <template v-slot="{ Component }">
    <component
      :is="Component"
      class="container"
      ref="componentRef"
    />
  </template>
</router-view>


I tried, getting Codegen node is missing for element/if/for node. Apply appropriate transforms first.

@aishwarya hm, probably a small syntax issue I guess. Give a try to an issue here: https://github.com/vuejs/router/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc
